# Submit Form via Axios to Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php

I have troubles with submitting a Form via Axios to Wordpress.
Wordpress needs an "action" in the transmitted data and don't accept JSON as far as I know.
So I created a URLSearchParams() object where I store my data, I want to send to wordpress.
The Problem is, that I want to send an array of objects to wordpress via Axios, but I can't receive it in PHP.

```
var params = new URLSearchParams()
params.append('action', 'save_form')
params.append("x", x)
params.append("y", y)
persons.map((person, index) => {
    params.append("myArr[]", JSON.stringify(myObj))
})
```

In PHP I want to receive the Objects like this, but because of URLSearchParams, the JSON is invalid...

```
foreach ($_POST["myArr"] as $myObjJson) {
    // json_decode() fails
    $myObj= json_decode($myObjJson);
}
```

How can I send the data from Javascript via Axios to my Wordpress-page and loop thru the array?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of sending using contact form 7.

```js
var name = $('#nameField').val();
var email = $('#emailField').val();
      
const dataup = new FormData();
      dataup.append("name", name);
      dataup.append("email", email);
      const response = axios
        .post(
          `https://yoursite.com/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/{ID-FORM}/feedback`,
          dataup
        )
        .then(function(response) {
          // ... action
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // ... action
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```